# error on mysqli::connect_errno

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to start working with mysqli and OOP, but it isn't working out that well. I can't get my mysqli methods working starting with a simple connect_errno method.

Can anyone help me out?

The connection to the database seems to be made, since I tried it with an other Password (access denied). With the correct Password I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::connect_errno() in
>   C:\xampp2\htdocs\badeendenrace\db\db.php on line 7

```
<?php
    $dbhost='localhost';
    $dbuser='Tjerk';
    $dbdata='badeendenrace';
    $dbpw='123test';
    $db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpw,$dbdata);
    if ($db->connect_errno())
    {
        echo "Connection failed: ".$db->connect_error()."\n";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

I'm using the latest version of Xampp (Reïnstalled it today) with PHP version 5.5.6

Comment: [`connect_errno`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php) isn't a function.

Answer (score 3):

As Rocket Hazmat said, `connect_errno` isn't a function. The same to `connect_error`. So just take away the round brackets after both in your code.

```
if ($db->connect_errno)
{
    echo "Connection failed: ".$db->connect_error."\n";
    exit();
}
```

Comment: @AlexKey: Look at the example Rocket Hazmat linked and look at this: [connect_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-error.php). The documentation says for connect_errno: _"Returns the error code from last connect call"_ and for connect_error: _"Returns a string description of the last connect error"_

Comment: I understand that, but for better quality of answer it is better idea to include explanation of why he should remove brackets.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have confused the object oriented function with the procedural. You mention OOP so I assume you want the OOP version.

```
$db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpw,$dbdata);
if ($db->connect_errno) //no parenthesis
{
    echo "Connection failed: ".$db->connect_error."\n"; //no parenthesis
    exit();
}
```

For procedural

```
$db = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpw,$dbdata);
if (!$db)
{
    echo "Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error(); //parenthesis
    exit();
}
```